# Certificate issue while migrating from jdk1.5 to jdk1.7

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

- I/O exception (org.apache.axis2.AxisFault) caught when processing request: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

After migrating from jdk 1.5 to jdk 1.7 i am getting sun.security.validator.ValidatorException.

Steps :
     Replaced jdk 1.5 with 1.7(includes jre).
     Compile the code with jdk1.7. Compilation was success.
     while  accessing the url with the certificate provided by the server i am getting sun.security.validator.ValidatorException in jdk1.7. But the exception is not thrown in jdk1.5.
     In cacerts file i have imported the specific certificate with alias name xxxx. If i access the url with the domain name as alias name in jdk1.7 name in certificate the exception is not thrown and works fine...

Do i need to do anything for migrating jdk1.5 to jdk1.7?
Do i really missing some thing in the above process?

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: What if you access the URL in a browser, or with `curl`?

Comment: Does your certificate contain a critical extension? [JDK Bug 6668231](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6668231) mentions a difference in behavior of Java 5 and 7. It also says _... must reject the certificate/CRL if it encounters a critical extension it does not recognize._

Comment: Which cacerts file did you import the certificate into?  And which JRE is actually being used when you run?  For example, on Windows, when you install a JDK, you are actually installing 2 JREs...one in the JDK folder, and one in the Java folder.

Answer (score 0):

Self signed certificate which was sent by server with no extensions.

version of the certificate is 1.

i am using /jdk1.7/jre/lib/security/cacerts with only jre 1.7. Also i have checked the cacerts file. Certificate details was updated properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153058/java7-refusing-to-trust-certificate-in-trust-store