# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException, fatal, description = certificate_unknown

Tags: java, ssl, bouncycastle, sslhandshakeexception, paho

There are many problems out there about SSLHandshakeException but still I am facing one of them. I am an absolute beginner regarding SSL/TLS, actually security in general.

**My problem:**

I am using the Java [Eclipse Paho](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/) mqtt library (windows7, oracle jdk1.8.0_65). My mqtt client is supposed to connect to a mqtt broker using a secured channel. I am basically using [this](https://gist.github.com/sharonbn/4104301) solution with small adaptations to make use of the latest Bouncy Castle library [from here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html). There I read in the received files I got from IT (`*.pem` CA certificate, a `*.crt` client certificate and `*.key` file) to set up the `TrustManagerFactory`, `KeyManagerFactory` and eventually create the `SSLContext` to set the `SocketFactory` in the `MqttConnectionOptions`.

When switching on SSL debugging, and trying to connect I observe the following handshake operation:

```
ssl://myserver.org:8883
adding as trusted cert:
...

***
found key for : private-key
chain[0]
...
```

Client sends its hello:

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1447336773 bytes = { .. , .. }
...
```

Server send its hello:

```
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 572699079 bytes = { .. , .. } -- (strange time stamp here)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]  
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
MQTT Con: TESTCLIENT1, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 6544
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
...
```

Now after the server passed its certificate chain I just get the following:

```
***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
MQTT Con: TESTCLIENT1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
MQTT Con: TESTCLIENT1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
MQTT Con: TESTCLIENT1, called closeSocket()
MQTT Con: TESTCLIENT1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
MQTT Con: TESTCLIENT1, called close()
MQTT Con: TESTCLIENT1, called closeInternal(true)
...
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
MQTT Con: TESTCLIENT1, setSoTimeout(30000) called
```

After that it seems there is just another try, and the client just sends another `*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2` where the server answers again with `*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2`. But I do not receive the expected `*** ServerHelloDone`.

**Solutions I tried:**

1.) Using the Java `keytool -importcert -alias ca-file.alias -file myPem.pem` I imported the `*.pem` into my truststore `cacerts` (I don't even know if this is needed).

2.) I tried to follow up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775155/pkix-path-does-not-chain-with-any-of-the-trust-anchors-error-in-windows-environm) solution which just removes the `TrustManager`, and does get me a bit further:

```
***
MQTT Con: TESTCLIENT1, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 333
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA1withRSA
...
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA1withRSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA512withRSA
Cert Authorities:
<Empty>
MQTT Con: TESTCLIENT1, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4
*** ServerHelloDone
matching alias: private-key
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
...
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
...
*** CertificateVerify
...
*** Finished
```

It really seems that it does get me through but 1.) that's not how it should be and 2.) then the mqtt client just does not return after the first `publish` call.

**My questions are now:**

1. How do I handle certificates and key files correctly in Java using the `TrustManagerFactory`, `KeyManagerFactory`, etc.?
2. What in general could be the problem with my connection setup?

Comment: What is correct depends on what cert is actually in *.pem and whether it is a root/anchor for the server's cert chain, or an intermediate or root/anchor for the client, or maybe both. Use `keytool -printcert -file (filename)` to see the "Owner" (Subject) and "Issuer" for that cert, compared to the Issuer in *.crt (which I presume you loaded with *.key into your keystore somehow) and the Owners and Issuers for the cert(s) used by the server with `keytool -printcert -sslserver (host):(port)`. ...

Comment: ... A TrustManager (from factory or not) should have only certs not keys; a KeyManager should have privatekey *and* matching cert chain, and need not have other certs, although if you load them both from the same file that file can have both. Also I don't understand why you care about "latest" BouncyCastle or how you are using it; BC doesn't provide SSL/TLS protocol through JCE (only lightweight) and doesn't provide any primitives for SSL/TLS that Oracle/openjdk 8 providers don't. (Many years ago in Java **6** BC did provide ECC when Sun didn't.)